# Meaning of pop off

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, expressions

1.Pop off rounds a tree
2.pop off rounds at a tree

I think meaning of *pop off means also *fire

So above two sentences is my matter that crossing out the preposition of *at or remain it? Or either will do?

Answer (score 4):

'Pop off' can indeed refer to the firing of a weapon, usually in an informal setting. Here, you need the preposition 'at' to show that you are sending your bullets towards the tree.